lylualatex lilypond error when compiling with MikTex
I am trying to compile a Latex document with lyluatex and a lilypond element. Here is the latex code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nofragment, program={c:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe}, pass-fonts]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
music = \relative {
c d e
}
\score {
\new ChoirStaff \with {
instrumentName = "2 Fl."
} <<
\new Staff \transpose c c' \music
\new Staff {
\clef bass
\music
}
>>
}
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}

When compiling from Texnic Center with
\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe
and command line option
-interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "%wm"
I get the following error:
Module lyluatex Info: Compiling score tmp-ly/504130eafb16e7b481f300c28c1a5064 wi
th LilyPond executable 'c:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe'. o
n input line 21
...Data/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:119: bad argument #2
 to 'gsub' (string/function/table expected)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'string.gsub'
    ...Data/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:119: in upvalue 'ex
tract_includepaths'
    ...Data/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:816: in method 'lil
ypond_cmd'
    ...Data/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1151: in method 'ru
n_lilypond'
    ...Data/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1115: in method 'pr
ocess'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}
                                                  
l.21 \end{lilypond}

A ly-file is generated, but apparently, Lilypond can not be executed. So I commented out line 119 in the file MiKTeX\scripts\lyluatex\lyluatex.lua according to the error message:
--        includepaths[i] = path:gsub('^ ', ''):gsub('^~', os.getenv("HOME")):gsub('^%.%.', './..')
Now the error message is:
Inserting `readline' in `process_input_buffer'.
Removing  `readline' from `process_input_buffer'.
Module lyluatex Info: Compiling score tmp-ly/504130eafb16e7b481f300c28c1a5064 wi
th LilyPond executable 'c:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe'. o
n input line 28
Module lyluatex Warning: The score doesn't contain any music:
(lyluatex)               this will probably cause bad output. on input line 28
...ppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: 
Module lyluatex Error: 
(lyluatex)             LilyPond failed to compile the score.
(lyluatex)             Please check the log file
(lyluatex)             and the generated LilyPond code in
(lyluatex)             tmp-ly/504130eafb16e7b481f300c28c1a5064.log
(lyluatex)             tmp-ly/504130eafb16e7b481f300c28c1a5064.ly
(lyluatex)             
(lyluatex)             on input line 28

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...ppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function <.
..ppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:108>
    (...tail calls...)
    ./lyluatex.lua:561: in method 'check_compilation'
    ./lyluatex.lua:1210: in method 'write_latex'
    ./lyluatex.lua:1134: in method 'process'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}


This brings me one step further: apparently, lualatex has found Lilypond and Lilypond has touched the Lilypond file generated before: a corresponding log file is generated, probably by Lilypond. The log file, however, is only a generic one:
Usage: lilypond [OPTION]... FILE...
Typeset music and/or produce MIDI from FILE.
LilyPond produces beautiful music notation.
For more information, see https://lilypond.org

When I double-click on the file 504130eafb16e7b481f300c28c1a5064.ly, a pdf snipped with music is generated, so the ly-file seems to be OK, and it can be processed by Lilypond.
Can anyone help me configuring my setup? Am I using versions that are not compatible with each other?
Here are the first lines from the log file, where version numbers are written:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4) (format=lualatex 2024.9.24)  24 SEP 2024 21:27
 system commands enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c

Lilypond version is lilypond-2.22.2-1.mingw.exe.
Thank you very much in advance for your help and your time!

Are you bound to Windows as a system? Lilypond and LaTeX are both out of the FOSS universe. Everything works a bit more smoothly on Linux. Therefore I would recommend in general to get some 5-10y/o laptop, slap ubuntu/debian/mint on it and run it there. If you expose a folder on your windows machine to the network, you can even mount it on linux and have your document compiled to the win machine.

Yes, I am bound to Windows as a system. A second laptop is not an option that works for me.

WSL2 would be another idea, if this helps. It doesn't solve your specific problem here right away, but on the long run it may and it might avoid running into others.

Yes, that sounds good. I don't need a second computer with the WSL2.

I think I solved it...
https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/issues/322
I was running Lilypond 2.22.2 when it worked. The issue was that the currentdir argument to the extract_includepaths function was null. You  have to add a case for that argument to be null.
ChatGPT be thanked...


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
